# Ubuntu crashes during installation

Tags: system-installation, laptop, crash

So I have been trying to install Ubuntu on my old Laptop (HP pavilion dv6)
However during the installation of ubuntu my it seems to crash and restart to windows when I choose 'Install inside of windows 7' option.
I have tried ubuntu 14.04 LTS and 15.04.
Hopefully someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: What is "Install inside of Windows" option? Is it wubi install? Or do you boot from LiveUSB?

Answer (score 0):

in order to install ubuntu 14.04 or 15.04 i had to remove the battery and make sure the laptop didn't overheat... which i find is a pain in the butt because I never had any issues of the type with windows on it... (other OS issues) but the problem persists even after install; laptop overheats, espexially during updates and crashes.

it hapend with both 14 and 15 I have a HP Pavilion G6

Answer (score -1):

Sorry if this is late but I can definitely relate to your problem.

I have a HP Pavilion DV6 2114sa and let me say first so far it has been a horrible laptop: really loud fan (even after cleaning and new thermal paste), overheated easily, idled at 60', HDMI and VGA are very much hit and miss if they work at all. Anyway back on topic.

I found the laptop after it had been thrown away by my dad when he got a new computer for the reasons above and I fixed it up as much as possible but windows was being a pain so I decided to install Ubuntu 14.04.2 from a disk and it ran but crashed all the time either the screen going black or vertical stripped lines. I don't know if you are having a similar crash but I decided to make a bootable USB for it and I got the same problem but not as often and I managed to install it on the 10th time. Unfortunately it still crashed when I booted it up. I decided that as it is an old laptop that is about 5 years old so I thought I would go for an older version so I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 and installed that onto a disk but the same problem. So I made another bootable USB with 12.04 and managed to install it on the second attempt. So far it is working fine.

Hope it helps.

(EDIT:Updated 12.04 from inside Ubuntu to 14.04 and it came up with the same problem. I am trying it with 12.10 now to see if I can get that one working. Will tell you how it goes.)

Comment: try to write answer to-the-point. That will save your's and the reader's time. Your above answer could have been **half** of it's length if written properly and to the topic.